# How to use all the space in extracted hard disk (remove leftover system folders)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I have extracted hard disks from otherwise dead Mac laptops.
I'm using them as external hard disks, but I cannot use all the space they contain because they have a few system folders (like `/Applications` or `/System`) which are of no use at all to me now.

It seems I cannot delete them using the terminal (even as `sudo`) or with Disk Utility (If I ask this app
to erase the whole volume it refuses).

Did I miss something? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I just realized that you most likely already did what I suggested in my answer, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into disk utility select `view` then `show all devices`. For the drive you want to erase, select the upper most text/name and then click `erase`. You can now chose the `name`, its `file system` (for normal use I would recommend MacOs Extended) and its `scheme` (you most likely want to have GUID). Unless its an SSD you can also select `security options` to securely erase the data.

Make sure that all files on all volumes and its partitions of that physical drive are backed up, since you will reformat and therefore erase the actual hard drive, not just a partition.

---

More info about the file systems: [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/disk-utility/dsku19ed921c/mac), [APFS vs MacOS Extended](https://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/osx/apfs-vs-mac-os-extended-which-mac-disk-format-is-best/)

Comment: Originally, I tried a variation of this, but on my second try I applied what you suggest here and it worked. Thanks

Comment: I am glad I could help you. Sometimes you just have to try things a second or third time and then it *magically* works ;)